# Unable to make Bitcoind commands

Tags: bitcoin-core, bitcoind, client, json-rpc, bitcoin-cli

I am attempting to make Bitcoin-RPC commands in the Windows 10 terminal using Bitcoind from the Bitcoin Core. However, whenever I start `C:\Program Files\Bitcoin\daemon>bitcoind` the terminal hangs and doesn't print anything. I've waited several hours and the terminal keeps loading and doesn't allow any input. I've also tried typing `C:\Program Files\Bitcoin\daemon>bitcoind -daemon` but `-daemon` is not valid Windows command.

I've also tried querying Bitcoin-cli with `C:\Program Files\Bitcoin\daemon>bitcoin-cli getinfo` but I get the error:

```
C:\Program Files\Bitcoin\daemon>bitcoin-cli getinfo
error: couldn't connect to server: EOF reached (code 1)
(make sure server is running and you are connecting to the correct RPC port)
```

So, after researching and reading other Stack Overflow questions I decided to check my bitcoin.conf file. I didn't have one, so I created one and placed it in the `C:\Users\User\AppData\Roaming\Bitcoin` directory. My bitcoin.conf file looks like:

```
rpcuser=user
rpcpassword=pass
rpcallowip=127.0.0.1
rpcport=8332 
rpcthreads=10 
server=1
```

But i'm still getting the same errors. Does anyone have any idea on what i'm doing wrong?

---

**Update:**

I typed in `tasklist` into the windows terminal and bitcoind.exe and Clientcore were running. Then I typed :`C:\Program Files\Bitcoin\daemon>bitcoin-cli -rpcuser=user -rpcpassword=pass -rpc
port=8332 getinfo`, but got another error:

```
error code: -28
error message:
Verifying blocks...
```

---

**Update:**

I tried `C:\Program Files\Bitcoin\daemon>bitcoin-cli -rpcuser=user -rpcpassword=pass -rpc
port=8332 getinfo` again a couple minutes later and it worked.

I opened one terminal and ran bitcoind, and another terminal I make the getinfo command and everything works

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this:

`bitcoin-cli -rpcuser=user -rpcpassword=pass -rpcport=8332 getinfo`

also make sure bitcoind is running, you can do that by
`ps -aux | grep bitcoind`

Comment: I'm on Windows so instead of `ps -aux | grep bitcoind` i typed `tasklist` into the terminal, and bitcoind and ClientCore were running. Then I typed `C:\Program Files\Bitcoin\daemon>bitcoin-cli -rpcuser=user -rpcpassword=pass -rpc` and got another error? 
`port=8332 getinfo
error code: -28
error message:
Verifying blocks...`

Comment: i tried again a couple minutes later and it worked. Thanks!!!